# Why there's a space between these tabs?

Tags: css

I tried to make tabs using CSS3 and got the following result:
[image]

With the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
nav{
    width:1000px;
    padding-top:30px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
nav ul.topnav{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
nav ul.topnav li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:173px;
    height:18px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:15px;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 5px #E7E4E9;
    border:1px solid #8C8293;
    border-radius:15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0;
    color:#666666;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul class="topnav">
<li>Overview</li>
<li>Alarms</li>
<li class="selected">Config</li>
<li>Logs</li>
<li>Command Line</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I remove that space between the tabs (as shown in the image)?
PS. It seems to be a trailing space because at the end of the list I have this space as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spaces are actually the newlines (whitespace) between your `<li>` tags. Since you made your `<li>`s inline blocks, the whitespace is treated as text on the same line as your inline blocks, causing them to be spaced apart.

You can either remove the newlines from your HTML, or float your `<li>`s instead of using `display: inline-block`:

```
nav ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You said "The spaces are actually the newlines (whitespace) between your <li> tags, since you made your <li>s inline blocks." What does making inline blocks have to do with spaces?. Wouldn't the space still be there if li's were just inline ? I got confused when I read the answer. It sounded like because the li's were inline blocks thats why the space is there .don't you agree ?

Comment: @Subhra: Yes, but there's nothing about `display: inline` here.

Answer (score 2):

It's the carriage return in the HTML markup.

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/8D26e/6/.

Comment: I have a div that follows it but now the tabs are overlapping it: http://jsfiddle.net/dcXgR/ How can I adjust the div to be below the tabs?

Comment: I found a more flexible solution (clearfix): http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/ But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try floating the `li`s. Or you can get rid of the spaces in your markup (between `<li>` and `<li>`). This happens when you use `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) before styling anything.

FYI: A CSS reset file is a file that nullifies all of the default styling given by browsers to HTML elements. Because browsers differ in that default style, designers usually consider this a good practice to first zero-out default styles by applying some sort of CSS reset, and then apply their own styles.

Comment: ok, it's good to know about CSS reset but that doesn't solve the problem. As replied in other questions, I have to use float.

Comment: I tried your example with CSS reset, and it worked. Did you try that too?

Comment: no, I actually don't need CSS reset because this code snippet is a part of a bigger project and we try to keep the number of lines to the minimum (embedded system). The solution is just one line of code as seen in the answer to this question above.

Answer (score -1):

Using google chrome ispector

http://www.threetipsaday.com/2008/12/debug-inspect-google-chrome-inspector/

you can change on the fly css parameters and discover which one generate a space beetween tabs.

Anyway I guess that you just need to change  padding:10px;(ul.topnav li) to padding:0px;(ul.topnav li)

Regards